# Cosa significa "fianata"?

Tags: word-meaning, single-words

In un post su Facebook (ora cancellato, ma riportato da molti giornali, tra cui il [Corriere](https://www.corriere.it/politica/18_maggio_23/di-battista-minaccia-mattarella-non-si-opponga-italiani-e5fdb078-5e9b-11e8-ab4f-a9009bdd5947.shtml) e [Repubblica](http://www.repubblica.it/politica/2018/05/23/news/padre_di_battista_bottura-197151725/)), Vittorio Di Battista, padre del politico del Movimento 5 Stelle Alessandro, ha usato la parola "fianate":

> I DOLORI DI MISTER ALLEGRIA
> È il papà di tutti noi.
> È quello che si preoccupa di varare un governo.
> È quello che ha avallato la legge elettorale che impedisce di varare un governo.
> Poveretto, quanto lo capisco.
> In più ci si mettono le **fianate** sul cv di Giuseppe Conte, le perdite in Borsa e la irresistibile ascesa dello spread.
> Poveretto, quanto lo capisco.
> [...]

Non capisco questa parola, e non la trovo su nessun vocabolario. L'unica cosa che ho trovato è che [il Fiano è un vino](https://www.garzantilinguistica.it/ricerca/?q=fiano), ma non so se c'entri qualcosa. Suppongo sia dialetto: nel caso può aiutare sapere che, [secondo Wikipedia](https://it.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alessandro_Di_Battista#Biografia), Alessandro è nato a Roma "da genitori di Civita Castellana", che è in provincia di Viterbo.

Per dare un po' di contesto: è un post in cui Vittorio Di Battista attacca Mattarella ("Mister Allegria"). Il Presidente della Repubblica stava vagliando la candidatura di Giuseppe Conte a premier, e Di Battista ha minacciato un'insurrezione violenta se Mattarella non gli avesse dato l'incarico di governo. Conte è stato fortemente criticato per aver aggiunto al proprio curriculum delle esperienze di studio che sembrano non essere state fatte, o, se sono state fatte, per averne esagerato l'importanza.

Dal contesto, "fianate" potrebbe significare "errori" (frutto dell'ubriachezza data dal vino Fiano?), ma vorrei una conferma, sia sul significato che sull'origine.

**Aggiornamento:**
Come segnalato [nei commenti](https://italian.stackexchange.com/questions/9470/cosa-significa-fianata#comment20834_9470) da abarisone, potrebbe essere un riferimento al deputato Emanuele Fiano, che in un [intervento a "Coffee Break" su La7](http://www.la7.it/coffee-break/video/emanuele-fiano-pd-su-giuseppe-conte-non-%C3%A8-la-prima-volta-che-i-5-stelle-cadono-sui-curricula-23-05-2018-242349) aveva appunto citato episodi analoghi da parte di altri membri del partito. La spiegazione mi sembrava convincente, ma Vittorio Di Battista ha pubblicato [un nuovo post su Facebook](https://www.facebook.com/vittorio.dibattista.3/posts/2109751232569663):

> AVVISO.
>
> Qualche fonte ha affermato che avrei cancellato il post su Mister Allegria.
> E' una **fianata**.
> Non ho cancellato un bel **fiano** di niente, è stato FB che ha oscurato il mio post.
> Maremma bucaiola...

A questo punto credo che il nome di Emanuele Fiano sia solo un'incredibile coincidenza, e sembra che Di Battista usi "fianata" come "cazzata": "le cazzate sul CV di Giuseppe Conte", "È una cazzata", "Non ho cancellato un bel cazzo di niente". Ma resta un'ipotesi, e sarei curioso di averne conferma.

Comment: [Fiano (Romano)](https://it.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fiano_Romano) è anche una località poco a nord di Roma, tutto sommato non lontanissima da Civita Castellana, se può servire a qualcosa. Che si attribuisca ai suoi abitanti uno scarso intelletto?

Comment: Purtroppo, i politici della Spagna sono ormai esperti in fare questo tipo di cose, e un modo molto più esagerato di quello di Conte.

Comment: Potrebbe essere anche un riferimento al deputato PD Emanuele Fiano che era [intervenuto a riguardo in una trasmissione tv](http://www.la7.it/coffee-break/video/emanuele-fiano-pd-su-giuseppe-conte-non-%C3%A8-la-prima-volta-che-i-5-stelle-cadono-sui-curricula-23-05-2018-242349).

Comment: Mi sembra probabile l’ipotesi di @abarisone.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Tenendo conto della dialettica, peraltro becera, che molto spesso si instaura tra sostenitori di un partito piuttosto che di un altro, non è raro che per denigrare l'avversario si storpi il cognome e lo si utilizzi al posto di un termine negativo o addirittura di una parolaccia.

In questo caso il termine fianata può essere un riferimento al deputato PD Emanuele Fiano che era [intervenuto a riguardo in una trasmissione tv](http://www.la7.it/coffee-break/video/emanuele-fiano-pd-su-giuseppe-conte-non-%C3%A8-la-prima-volta-che-i-5-stelle-cadono-sui-curricula-23-05-2018-242349).

Nel dizionario Treccani dei neologismi è, ad esempio, presente il termine [berlusconata](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/berlusconata_%28Neologismi%29/):

> **berlusconata** s. f. (*iron.*) Comportamento o affermazione tipici di
>   Silvio Berlusconi. ◆ I collaboratori cercano disperatamente di farla
>   passare per l’ennesima «berlusconata»: parole in libertà del
>   presidente del Consiglio contro i giudici che sarebbero «mentalmente
>   disturbati», affetti da «turbe psichiche». (Massimo Franco, *Corriere
>   della sera*, 5 settembre 2003, p. 2, In primo piano)

che ha un significato simile a quello di fianata nel contesto da te citato.